# Optimize Excel function that reduces manual input in formule with offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to rewrite my formula below so I reduce manual input. I am looking to reduce the number of times I have to call the offset function, each time with a different col argument, and rather use a range of cols as input.

this is the formula:
MAX(SUM(OFFSET(C3,0,COLUMNS(C3:C3)-1,1,$A$3)),SUM(OFFSET(C3,0,COLUMNS(C3:D3)-1,1,$A$3)),SUM(OFFSET(C3,0,COLUMNS(C3:E3)-1,1,$A$3)),SUM(OFFSET(C3,0,COLUMNS(C3:F3)-1,1,$A$3)))

Can anybody help? Thanks!

I tried using the sequence function: MAX(SUM(OFFSET(C3,0,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($C$3:$F$3)-1,0,1),1,$A$3)))

but that didn't work and I don't know why.

So an example: for the first row, I want to look for every 4 columns what the sum is (S0 B1:E1 (which is 2), C1:F1, (which is 1), D1:G1, E1:H1, F1:I1, G1:J1) and then give me the max of these options, which would be 2. For the second row, exactly the same thing but instead of 4 columns, look for every 3 columns.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve? Please provide the input and the expected output. Maybe there are other ways of doing it without using the `OFFSET` function that is a volatile funciton.

Comment: Hi David; thanks for your reply! What I am trying to do is, for each row look at n consecutive columns and count their values, and try to find the n consecutive columns that have the highest sum. So, for example, for n=4,  I want to look at A1:A4, A2:A5, A3:A6 etc; see what the sum is of the values in those ranges and then look for the maximum of the sums. Hope that makes sense

Comment: this is your friend, :-) https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: You can use the generator to paste your Excel data, to generate a markdown table that you can paste in your post to share the data in table form. That way we can easily copy any sample you provide and not all having to make up data ourselves.

Comment: `$C$3:$F3$3` is a typo in your formula

Comment: Oops sorry; very new to this! I edited my question with some example data

Comment: The idea is to get some examples with that and expected outcome.

Comment: please note that your formula starts from column C and your explanation starts from B. Also the addition of increasing number of columns if the row increases is not the initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases OFFSET can be avoided by replacing it with INDEX. The benefit of that is that INDEX is not volatile and therefore your formula(s) will not recalculate at *any* change within the file like with OFFSET.

We can use the following in Microsoft 365:

```
=MAX(MMULT(INDEX(C3:K3,,SEQUENCE(,A3)+SEQUENCE(4,,0)),SEQUENCE(A3,,,0)))
```

Where `SEQUENCE(,A3)+SEQUENCE(4,,0)` provides the indexed column numbers row wise:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

and MMULT provides a way to sum this indexed matrix by row. And results in an array of the sums by row. MAX takes out the maximum sum.

EDIT: with provided sample and explanation,

This can be used to create the offset using index:

`=MAX(MMULT(IFERROR(INDEX(B2:J2,,SEQUENCE(,A2)+SEQUENCE(4,,0)),0),SEQUENCE(A2,,,0)))`

Comment: Or to spill it: `=LET(a,A2:A15,MAP(ROW(a),LAMBDA(x,LET(y,INDEX(a,x-1),MAX(MMULT(IFERROR(INDEX(B:J,x,SEQUENCE(,y)+SEQUENCE(4,,0)),0),SEQUENCE(y,,,0)))))))`

Comment: Glad to be helpful. You can mark the question as being answered by clicking the `V` next to my answer.